# General way to find monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Is there any general way to find 'one' monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$? Does there exist any algorithm to find it?

Comment: I'd venture to guess the answer is no.

Comment: Irreducible over which field? $x^n+2x^{n-1}+\cdots+ 2x+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ by Eisenstein's criterion for any $n>0$.

Comment: I can see now that you have the finite-fields tag. In that case, there are algorithms for computing Conway polynomials, e.g. http://eprints.cs.vt.edu/archive/00000493/ and a database at http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Frank.Luebeck/data/ConwayPol/index.html?LANG=en

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1654562/11619).

Comment: [Related 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340149/11619).

Comment: [Related 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/215469/11619), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70127/11619).

Comment: Anyway, a degree $n$ monic polynomial over $\Bbb{F}_p$ is irreducible with probability very close to $1/n$. So with an efficient irreducibility test in place you can find one by random poking soon enough.

Comment: (cont'd) But asking for a specific one is asking a lot (apart from the few lists linked to above). The reason for the difficulty is pretty much the same why we don't have a simpe formula that always produces a prime number. The case of irreducible polynomials modulo $p$ is a little bit easier than that of prime numbers (definite version of Rabin-Miller-Fermat style tests, the analogue of Riemann hypothesis is a theorem, etc), but still.